# How to check user role and show select option in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I have users with different roles, like Admin,Employee,Secretary,etc.

And i have a page for send letter, in this page i have a `select option` to show indicators.

I want when user with Secretary role open this page, see all of the indicators but other users with other roles just see one indicator like internal letters, how can i do this ?

I have a relation between `role` and `user` :

**User Model**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

**Role Model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

This is `select option` in send letter page :

```
<select class="col-12 border mt-2 pt-2" name="indicator_id">
        @foreach($indicators as $indicator)
                <option value="{{ $indicator->id }}">{{ $indicator->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

As you can see, indicators comes from somewhere else.

This is **Letter Controller** to show send letter page :

```
$indicators = Indicator::all();
return view('Letter.add', compact('indicators'));
```

Comment: show you letter contoller little more the full method && your your user can act as all roles??

Comment: Why not create a relation oneToMany $role->indicators so that for the authentificated user you can do auth() - >user()->role->indicators which will hold only indicators specific for the user. There is some work to do that but it's safer on long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function to your **User** Model which checks for the user role:

```
   /**
 * Check if this user belongs to a role
 *
 * @return bool
 */
 public function hasRole($role_name)
 {
     foreach ($this->roles as $role){

         //I assumed the column which holds the role name is called role_name
         if ($role->role_name == $role_name)
             return true;
      }
     return false;
 }
```

Now in your view you call it like so:

```
<select class="col-12 border mt-2 pt-2" name="indicator_id">
    @foreach($indicators as $indicator)    
          @if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Secretary'))
                <option value="{{ $indicator->id }}">{{ $indicator->name }}</option>
          @elseif (!Auth::user()->hasRole('Secretary') && {{ $indicator->name }} == 'internalLetter')
               <option value="{{ $indicator->id }}">Internal Letter</option>
          @endif
    @endforeach   

</select>
```

Comment: Internal letter must be shown for Secretary and other users

Comment: I mean, internal letter would have existed for both

Comment: If the `$indicators` holds the value of *internal letter* then it will show for both.

Comment: Edited it should now display all indicators for `secretary` role and *internal letters* for other roles.